# State not changing after update from use state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm new to React. I'm trying to make my socket io listener work. When I it out of `useEffect` it works but it is called several times. In `useEffect` it is called only once (which is good obviously) but this time `users` are not updated - initial value.

```
function Users() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers();

        if(users.length > 0) {
            socket.on("statusChange", (data) => {
                console.log(users); // this returns initial state of users
                let tempUsers = [...users];
                let ndx = tempUsers.findIndex(obj => obj.id === data.id);
                if(ndx === -1)
                    return;

                tempUsers[ndx].status = data.status;
                setUsers(tempUsers);
            });
        }
    }, []);

    function getUsers() {
        fetch(/* stuff */)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setUsers(res.data));
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.usersContainer}>
                { users.map((user, i) => <UserCard key={i} user={user} />) }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of simply executing getUsers, use it with a callback. And then in the callBack execute setUsers:

```js
function Users() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(/* stuff */)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          if(res.data.length > 0) {
            socket.on("statusChange", (data) => {
                console.log(res.data); // this returns initial state of users
                let tempUsers = [...res.data];
                let ndx = tempUsers.findIndex(obj => obj.id === data.id);
                if(ndx === -1)
                    return;

                tempUsers[ndx].status = data.status;
                setUsers(tempUsers);
            });
        }
        
        });
    }, []);


    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.usersContainer}>
                { users.map((user, i) => <UserCard key={i} user={user} />) }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Users;
```

Comment: My `statusChange` right now works. Problem is that when I fetch my data for the first time they are not set to the `users` state. What do you suggest?

Comment: getUsers() will take time to pull the users so setUsers state will be invoked later. by the time user information is pulled from api and state is set, it will execute the code in useEffect and come out of it. That is the reason it is not working for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Some parts where I'm making assumptions:

1. `getUsers()` should be called only once: when the component mounts
2. We want to listen to `socket.on("statusChange")` and get updates about users we got from `getUsers()`.

```js
// This is pulled outside the component.
function getUsers() {
  fetch(/* stuff */)
  .then(res => res.json());
}

function Users() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    // Fetch users only once, when the component mounts.
    useEffect(() => {
      getUsers().then(res => {
        setUsers(res.data);
      });
    }, []);

    // Listen to changes
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!users.length) return;

      const listener = (data) => {
        // Functional update
        // See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates
        setUsers(prevUsers => {
          let nextUsers = [...prevUsers];
          let ndx = nextUsers.findIndex(obj => obj.id === data.id);
          
          // What's up here? See below.
          if(ndx === -1) return nextUsers;

          nextUsers[ndx].status = data.status;
          return nextUsers;
        });
      };

      socket.on("statusChange", listener);

      // Unsubscribe when this component unmounts
      // See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1
      return () => socket.off("details", listener);
    }, [users]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div className={styles.usersContainer}>
                { users.map((user, i) => <UserCard key={i} user={user} />) }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Users;
```

About `if(ndx === -1) return nextUsers;`

This means that `users` will never change in size, i.e. you won't handle data about a new user.

Alternatively, you could do `if(ndx === -1) return [ ...nextUsers, data ];`